# Having problems with jquery's ':last'

Tags: jquery

Ok so the principle of what I'm trying to accomplish is quite simple. I have a menu with an unknown (user selectable) number of items.

What happens is simple, we check the menu's width against the width of the window, then we say, ok, add a class to the last item to hide it, so the menu doesn't overflow it's container.

It's a bit spotty though, it *kinda* works (try resizing the jsfiddle), but there's some problems.

1. It only removes the *very last* `li` on DOM load.
2. Resizing the window to make it smaller works pretty perfect, removes each item from last - first (as intended).

   3. Resizing the window to make it larger doesn't seem to remove the class from `li:hidden:first` (why not?).

Code:-

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(e){

        var topmenucontain = $(".top-menu-contain").width();
        var brandwidth = $(".brand").width();
        var navwidth = $(".nav-button").width();


        var lastivisblelength = $(".top-menu-contain").find('li:visible:last').width(); //we must factor in the width of the last visible item so the menu doesn't overflow it's container.

        if ($(window).width() < topmenucontain + brandwidth + navwidth + lastivisblelength) {
           $(".top-menu-contain").find('li:visible:last').addClass('last-visible');
        }
        else {
           $(".top-menu-contain").find('li:hidden:first').removeClass('last-visible');
        }

        //opacity is zero by default, once calculations are made, fade the menu in.
        $(".top-menu-contain").animate({ opacity: 1 });


    });
```

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ofcy8j83/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not the best approach, because even if you make it work properly (hard because each `<li>` have different size, it will be not the best from the point of view of performance and usability. I would strong suggest to use [@media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for this kind of things, different menu design for different window sizes is the most usual pattern.

Anyway, to make this work, you need to use something like:

```
$(window).on("load ready resize",function(e){

    var topmenucontain = $(".top-menu-contain").width();
    var lastivisblelength = $(".top-menu-contain").find('li:visible:last').width();


    if ($(window).width() < topmenucontain + lastivisblelength) {

       while($(window).width() < topmenucontain + lastivisblelength){
           $(".top-menu-contain").find('li:visible:last').addClass('last-visible');
           topmenucontain = $(".top-menu-contain").width();
           lastivisblelength = $(".top-menu-contain").find('li:visible:last').width();
       }
    }
    else {
       $(".top-menu-contain").find('li.last-visible').first().removeClass('last-visible');
    }
});
```

I'm sure is not the best solution and haven't tested yet, but you can see the idea.

Comment: See my comment in reply to adeneo below as to why I can't really use media queries.

Comment: btw, that works, problem now is point 1., ie only adding the class to the last item onload. (when there could be a dozen li's in need of 'hiding').

Comment: @andy, I didn't see the first point, sorry, I got lost in the second, hehe, just change the `if` statement for `while`

Comment: Urgh, see my edit, I'm getting an 'Unexpected token else', since my implementation has two other variables and different html, can't see why. (yours certainly works though, tested on the jsfiddle).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$(".top-menu-contain").find('li:hidden:first').removeClass('last-visible');
```

use:

```
$(".top-menu-contain").find('li.last-visible:first').removeClass('last-visible');
```

Comment: The `else {    } ` is meant to find already hidden items and remove the class that hides them.

Comment: In your case, .last-visible has display:none, so if we select the first li with the last-visible class, we're actually selecting the first hidden element. What's wrong with that?

Comment: What's wrong is that it's exactly the same thing as the jquery is already doing (and it doesn't work).